# Rescaled Coordinates in a polynomial equation.

Tags: perturbation-theory

I have this question from Murdock's textbook called: "Perturbations: Methods and Theory":
Use rescaling to solve: $\phi(x,\epsilon) = \epsilon x^2 + x+1 = 0$ and $\varphi (x,\epsilon) = \epsilon x^3+ x^2 - 4=0$.

I'll write my attempt at solving these two equations, first the first polynomial.

According to the book I first need to find an undetermined gauge that solves the above equation when $\epsilon = 0$, which means I need to guess $x \approx -1 +y \delta_1(\epsilon)$, now I plug it back to the above equation to find the following equation:
$$\epsilon -2y\epsilon \delta_1 + y^2 \delta_1^2 \epsilon +y \delta_1 = 0 $$

Now my problem is in finding a suitable gauge for $\delta_1(\epsilon)$ that solves the above last equation, it should be proportional to some power of $\epsilon$, i.e $\epsilon^r$, such that higher powers of $\epsilon$ in the last equation get neglected and we can find a solution for $y$ which gives a non-zero solution to $y$, but I don't see it.

Any help?

Comment: Both equations are polynomials. In your equation for $y$, you have terms $O(\epsilon)$, $O(\epsilon^{1+r}$, $O(\epsilon^{1+2r}$, and $O(\epsilon^r)$. What $r>0$ balances at least two of those terms, and leaves the unbalanced terms much smaller? There is another problem here in that your equation is quadratic and you're only seeing a single root. Your assumption that $x\approx-1$ is not necessarily true.

Comment: @David then how do you suggest me to solve this problem?

Comment: Let $x=\epsilon^\alpha x_0+\epsilon^\beta x_1+\ldots$ with $\alpha<\beta<\ldots$, and determine $\alpha$ using dominant balance.

Comment: @David I found following two solutions, one is for $\alpha = -1 , \beta = 0 $ and the other for $\alpha = -2/3 , \beta = -1/3$, am I right? thanks! It's a little a bit annoying this format of answer and questions and not a discussion, but I don't have control over where most people spend their time in helping others.

Comment: $-2/3,-1/3$ isn't a balance, because the term $\epsilon x^2=O(\epsilon^{-1/3})$ and the term $x=O(\epsilon^{-2/3})$ (and $1=O(1)$). The choice $x\approx\epsilon^{-1}x_0+x_1+\epsilon x_2+\ldots$ is correct. Usually once you find the first two powers you can safely assume the pattern continues. Your approximations then are $x=-1/\epsilon+1+O(\epsilon)$ and $x=-1+O(\epsilon)$ (this is the root you were getting when you started with $x\approx-1+y\delta_1(\epsilon)$).